# In NestJS's microservices, is gRPC connection between gRPC modules impossible?

Tags: typescript, logging, nestjs, microservices, grpc

I am a junior developer that learning a microservice in NestJS.

To learn microservice, I created two project named core and client.

The core project has a role as a API gateway. Simply, it receives all REST API request(HTTP Protocol).

Additionally, the core project also has a gRPC service method as a module. (named ACCO)

And, the core project has a inherit module that refers the client project's user service(gRPC method).

At the opposite, the client project has a gRPC service method and provides it to core project (named User).

In this case, I'd like to call the core project's acco module's service method inside the client proejct's user module's service.

To do that, I receive a user request via the core project's user controller like this.

```js
@Controller('user-svc')
export class UserSvcController {
  private logger = new Logger(UserSvcController.name);

  constructor(private readonly userSvcService: UserSvcService) {}

  @Get(':id')
  async getUser(@Param() params): Promise<GetUserResponse> {
    this.logger.debug(`call: params=${JSON.stringify(params)}`);
    return this.userSvcService.getUser(params.id);
  }
}
```

And, i throw it to the user-svc's service that inherit the client project's user service.

```js
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { GetUserRequest } from '../dtos/get-user-request.interface';
import { GetUserResponse } from '../dtos/get-user-response.interface';
import { Injectable, Logger, OnModuleInit } from '@nestjs/common';
import { userGrpcClientOptions } from '../protos/user-grpc.option';
import { Client, ClientGrpc } from '@nestjs/microservices';

interface IUserService {
  getUser(data: GetUserRequest): Observable<GetUserResponse>;
}

@Injectable()
export class UserSvcService implements OnModuleInit {
  private logger = new Logger(UserSvcService.name);

  @Client(userGrpcClientOptions) private readonly client: ClientGrpc;
  private userService: IUserService;

  onModuleInit() {
    this.logger.debug(`UserSvcService.onModuleInit`);
    this.userService = this.client.getService<IUserService>('UserService');
  }

  async getUser(id: string): Promise<GetUserResponse> {
    const user: Observable<GetUserResponse> = this.userService.getUser({
      id: id,
    } as GetUserRequest);

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      user.subscribe({
        next: (getUserResponse: GetUserResponse) => {
          this.logger.debug(
            `getUser=${JSON.stringify(getUserResponse, null, 2)}`,
          );
          resolve(getUserResponse);
        },
        error: (err) => {
          this.logger.error(`err=${JSON.stringify(err, null, 2)}`);
          reject(err);
        },
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Then, the client project's user grpc client was called and executed this code.

```js
import {
  BadRequestException,
  forwardRef,
  Inject,
  Injectable,
  Logger,
} from '@nestjs/common';
import { GetUserRequest } from '../dto/get-user-request.interface';
import { GetUserResponse } from '../dto/get-user-response.interface';
import { AccoSvcService } from '../../acco-svc/services/acco-svc.service';
import { FindAllByOwnerUidRequest } from '../../acco-svc/dto/find-all-by-owner-uid.request';

@Injectable()
export class UserService {
  private logger = new Logger(UserService.name);

  constructor(
    @Inject(forwardRef(() => AccoSvcService))
    private readonly accoService: AccoSvcService,
  ) {}

  async create(data: GetUserRequest): Promise<GetUserResponse> {
    const accoIds: string[] = await this.accoService
      .findAllByOwnerUid({ ownerUid: data.id } as FindAllByOwnerUidRequest)
      .then((response) => {
        return response.accoIds;
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        this.logger.error(`findByUid ${data.id} ${err}`);
        throw new BadRequestException(err);
      });
    this.logger.debug(`findByUid ${data.id} ${accoIds}`);

    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      resolve({
        username: 'test',
      });
    });
  }
}
```

On that code, the **accoService's findAllByOwnerUid** method was called.

That method is pointing the client project's **acco-svc** module's service.

```js
import { Inject, Injectable, Logger, OnModuleInit } from '@nestjs/common';
import { accoGrpcClientOptions } from '../protos/acco-grpc.option';
import { Client, ClientGrpc } from '@nestjs/microservices';
import { FindAllByOwnerUidRequest } from '../dto/find-all-by-owner-uid.request';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { FindAllByOwnerUidResponse } from '../dto/find-all-by-owner-uid.response';

interface IAccoService {
  findAllByOwnerUid(
    data: FindAllByOwnerUidRequest,
  ): Observable<FindAllByOwnerUidResponse>;
}

@Injectable()
export class AccoSvcService implements OnModuleInit {
  private logger = new Logger(AccoSvcService.name);

  @Client(accoGrpcClientOptions) private readonly client: ClientGrpc;
  private accoService: IAccoService;

  async onModuleInit() {
    this.logger.debug(`AccoSvcService.onModuleInit`);
    this.accoService = await this.client.getService<IAccoService>(
      'AccoService',
    );
  }

  async findAllByOwnerUid(
    data: FindAllByOwnerUidRequest,
  ): Promise<FindAllByOwnerUidResponse> {
    this.logger.debug(
      `findAllByOwnerUid in AccoService ${JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)}`,
    );
    try {
      const accoIds: Observable<FindAllByOwnerUidResponse> =
        this.accoService.findAllByOwnerUid(data);

      this.logger.debug(
        `findAllByOwnerUid after calling accoService ${data.ownerUid}`,
      );
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        accoIds.subscribe({
          next: (value: FindAllByOwnerUidResponse) => {
            this.logger.debug(
              `findAllByOwnerUid ${JSON.stringify(value, null, 2)}`,
            );
            resolve(value);
          },
          error: (err: any) => {
            this.logger.error(`findAllByOwnerUid ${err}`);
            reject(err);
          },
        });
      });
    } catch (err) {
      this.logger.error(`acco-svc-service's findAllByOwnerUid ${err}`);
    }
  }
}
```

it is pointing the core project's acco module's service.

```js
import { Injectable, Logger } from '@nestjs/common';
import { FindAllByOwnerUidResponse } from '../dtos/find-all-by-owner-uid.response';

@Injectable()
export class AccoService {
  private logger = new Logger(AccoService.name);

  findAll() {
    return `This action returns all acco`;
  }

  async findAllByOwnerUid(uid: string): Promise<FindAllByOwnerUidResponse> {
    this.logger.log(
      `In Acco Service, getUserResponse=${JSON.stringify(uid, null, 2)}`,
    );

    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      resolve({
        accoIds: ['1', '2'],
      } as FindAllByOwnerUidResponse);
    });
  }
}
```

And, that AccoService is injected the gRPC method by controller like this.

```js
import { Controller, Get, Logger } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AccoService } from '../services/acco.service';
import { GrpcMethod } from '@nestjs/microservices';
import { FindAllByOwnerUidRequest } from '../dtos/find-all-by-owner-uid.request';
import { FindAllByOwnerUidResponse } from '../dtos/find-all-by-owner-uid.response';

@Controller('acco')
export class AccoController {
  private logger = new Logger(AccoController.name);

  constructor(private readonly accoService: AccoService) {}

  @GrpcMethod('AccoService', 'FindAllByOwnerUid')
  async findAllByOwnerUid(
    data: FindAllByOwnerUidRequest,
  ): Promise<FindAllByOwnerUidResponse> {
    this.logger.log(
      `Acco Controller findAllByOwnerUid: ${JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)}`,
    );
    return await this.accoService.findAllByOwnerUid(data.ownerUid);
  }

  @Get()
  findAll() {
    return this.accoService.findAll();
  }
}
```

The data's flow is over.

But, when I call the core project's user-svc api with http protocol, this error is occurred.

```
[Nest] 9484  - 03/02/2023, 4:15:09 PM   ERROR [AccoSvcService] acco-svc-service's findAllByOwnerUid TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'findAllByOwnerUid')
[Nest] 9484  - 03/02/2023, 4:15:09 PM   ERROR [UserService] findByUid 123 TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'accoIds')
[Nest] 9484  - 03/02/2023, 4:15:09 PM    WARN DEPRECATED! Passing the error cause as the first argument to HttpException constructor is deprecated. You should use the "options" parameter instead: new HttpException("message", 400, { cause: new Error("Some Error") }) 
[Nest] 9484  - 03/02/2023, 4:15:09 PM   ERROR [RpcExceptionsHandler] Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'accoIds')
BadRequestException: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'accoIds')
    at /Users/ihyeonjun/WebstormProjects/mcservice1/src/user/services/user.service.ts:30:15
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at UserService.create (/Users/ihyeonjun/WebstormProjects/mcservice1/src/user/services/user.service.ts:23:31)
    at /Users/ihyeonjun/WebstormProjects/mcservice1/node_modules/@nestjs/microservices/context/rpc-proxy.js:11:32
    at Object.GetUser (/Users/ihyeonjun/WebstormProjects/mcservice1/node_modules/@nestjs/microservices/server/server-grpc.js:148:40)
```

I tried to convey the overall code flow as much as possible, but I think reading ability will decrease if it gets too long, so I will leave the flag address of each core and client project.

[Client Project](https://github.com/ggj0418/nestjs-mc-client)
[Core Project](https://github.com/ggj0418/nestjs-mc-core)

I set the **USER_GRPC_URL** as a localhost:50051 and **ACCO_GRPC_URL** as a localhost:50052.

Please help me...